# Trimming, Winsorising and manipulating biological data

Tags: dataset, trimmed-mean

So I have an experiment with multiple groups (groups 1-6), individuals in each group (n=10), and read outs per individual. Eg. below

> Group 1: 28.1, 28.6, 29, 30.3,30.4,30.6,30.7,31.1.34
>
> Group 2: 27.8,    28.3,   30.2,   31.3,   31.6,   31.8,   32.9,   33.8,   34.2,   35.5,   42.1

Now as this is a biological dataset, there are variations (which when looking from my biological eye is an outlier (eg. subject with value 42.1).

Now when I trim/winsorise the whole dataset (removing top most and bottom-most from every group) the variances make sense.

The question is, as I have multiple readouts from the same subject, when I trim the dataset for readout 1, and say exclude 2 subjects (top and bottom) from each group, will those 2 subjects have to be excluded from other readouts also?  Or can I freshly trim the datasets again, on a per read out basis ?

Statistically and biologically, I am asking different questions with each readout.

Comment: Neither: if you have many measurements for the same individuals, then you have a multivariate problem and you should use multivariate trimming/winsorizing method (because multivariate outliers need not stand out as outliers on any particular measurements). Search this site for multivariate outliers detection approaches.

Comment: @user603 Thanks. Is it the same case even if the readouts are technically independent of each other?

Comment: yes, because the *individual* may be an outlier (think weight heights and diets measurements on many normal people)